# Google Tag Manager V2 Issue: "Invalid input. You may have stale data; refresh the page and try again." when creating new container

Tags: google-tag-manager

Keep getting this error when trying to create my first account/container in the new interface: http://screencast.com/t/GHla6fpBkRE

I found this discussion on github: "[Failure to create container can leave behind state requiring manual intervention](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fgoogle%2Flmctfy%2Fissues%2F37&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNGA-9MJsEhzB4h4hJ2K1SduV-Ffow)" - I'm guessing this is what I'm experiencing right now? How would i get someone to take a look at this? We are planning on moving tracking for several major properties in to GTM but we want to verify there won't be any issues with V2 first. Guess this isn't a great sign :P Everything works fine in my other Google account, it's just this one.

Comment: The type of container referenced in the github link is not related to a Google Tag Manager container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed to create a tag, can't publish an empty container